# JavaFX Line segment width

Tags: java, javafx, 2d, line

I have some code which responds to key presses, and draws points and line segments correspondingly. However, the width of the line segments seems to alternate, even though I don't touch the line stroke width in the code. I'm wondering why this is happening.

Here is the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

public class DrawLineSegments extends Application {

    static double x = 0.0;
    static double y = 0.0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Pane p = new Pane();

        Rectangle border = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 100);
        border.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        Rectangle initialPoint = new Rectangle(border.getWidth() / 2, border.getHeight() / 2, 2, 2);
        initialPoint.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        x = border.getWidth() / 2;
        y = border.getHeight() / 2;

        p.getChildren().addAll(border, initialPoint);

        p.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {

            switch (e.getCode()) {

            case UP : 
                Line upLine = new Line(x + 1, y + 1, x + 1, y + 1 - 7.5);
                y = y - 7.5;
                upLine.setStroke(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
                upLine.setFill(Color.SANDYBROWN);
                p.getChildren().add(upLine);
                p.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(x, y, 2, 2));
                break;

            case DOWN : 
                Line downLine = new Line(x + 1, y + 1, x + 1, y + 1 + 7.5);
                y = y + 7.5;
                downLine.setStroke(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
                downLine.setFill(Color.SANDYBROWN);
                p.getChildren().add(downLine);
                p.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(x, y, 2, 2));
                break;

            case LEFT : 
                Line leftLine = new Line(x - 7.5, y + 1, x + 1, y + 1);
                x = x - 7.5;
                leftLine.setStroke(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
                leftLine.setFill(Color.SANDYBROWN);
                p.getChildren().add(leftLine);
                p.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(x, y, 2, 2));
                break;

            case RIGHT : 
                Line rightLine = new Line(x + 7.5, y + 1, x + 1, y + 1);
                x = x + 7.5;
                rightLine.setStroke(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
                rightLine.setFill(Color.SANDYBROWN);
                p.getChildren().add(rightLine);
                p.getChildren().add(new Rectangle(x, y, 2, 2));
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(p);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Draw Line Segments");
        primaryStage.show();

        p.requestFocus();

    }

}
```

And an image that perhaps better explains what I'm asking:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read up on the [Coordinate System of a Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html)

> **Coordinate System**
>
> The Node class defines a traditional computer graphics "local"
>   coordinate system in which the x axis increases to the right and the y
>   axis increases downwards. The concrete node classes for shapes provide
>   variables for defining the geometry and location of the shape within
>   this local coordinate space. For example, Rectangle provides x, y,
>   width, height variables while Circle provides centerX, centerY, and
>   radius.
>
> At the device pixel level, integer coordinates map onto the corners
>   and cracks between the pixels and the centers of the pixels appear at
>   the midpoints between integer pixel locations. Because all coordinate
>   values are specified with floating point numbers, coordinates can
>   precisely point to these corners (when the floating point values have
>   exact integer values) or to any location on the pixel. For example, a
>   coordinate of (0.5, 0.5) would point to the center of the upper left
>   pixel on the Stage. Similarly, a rectangle at (0, 0) with dimensions
>   of 10 by 10 would span from the upper left corner of the upper left
>   pixel on the Stage to the lower right corner of the 10th pixel on the
>   10th scanline. The pixel center of the last pixel inside that
>   rectangle would be at the coordinates (9.5, 9.5).

Regarding your problem: Don't use 7.5. Instead use 7 or 8.